# What does "the heel that she snaps" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury),  plaintiff attorney, Rohr and Ranking Fitch, a jury consultant
of the defendants, the gun manufacturers discuss about the victim, Jacob Wood:

> Rankin Fitch: What do you hope to achieve if you win? You'll bring
> Jacob Wood back to life? No. You just ensure that his wife goes to the
> cemetery in a better car. That **the heel that she snaps** on the way to
> the graveside...belongs to a $1200 shoe. And you get your name in the
> paper.

What does "the heel that she snaps" mean?
It look so different version of a idiom: **snap at sb's heels**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with 'snapping at someone's heels'. The reference is (presumably) to shoes with stiletto heels. The widow would be wearing expensive shoes, if she should happen to break one of her heels.